# Need to know Number Format of below given format

Tags: java, format, numbers, hex, converters

I need to determine the format of the following numbers, which are somehow based on a method used in the Automobile industry to store meter values such as "total number of kilometers". I found it in a magazine article, and I already tried UTF-8/16/32 and hexadecimal

```
decimal number = 136
related number is : FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 05 49 B2 00 05

decimal number = 550
related number is : FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 15 6A 81 00 15
```

Comment: Hey! Have you found the numbers on the ground? Or were they written in the clouds? Please add some context to the question.

Comment: @akuzminykh Wrote them down in a fever dream while examining [Kryptos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptos#/media/File:Kryptos_sculptor.jpg)...

Comment: @akuzminykh I found them in an article. It only contains decimal numbers and the other type of number is "HEX" as they mentioned. I need to know the mechanism or how it converts

Comment: @ElliottFrisch hey, I also no Idea. I am trying to match both numbers using exist converters, but still no idea

Comment: @Ranish You can try it on [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). The chance should be higher that someone there will know it.

Comment: The first related number is 340282366920938463463374325979502739461 in decimal. The second related number is 340282366920938463463374326048772653077 in decimal. The difference between the related numbers is 69269913616 (in decimal). Alternatively, the first decimal value is "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88" in hex and the second is "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 26". Now what kind of cryptography are you studying in class? I suppose, if desperate, you could [turn this in](https://xkcd.com/538/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch hey, I am not studying cryptography. It is a method used in the Automobile industry to store meter values such as "total number of kilometers"

Comment: @Ranish Do not start a question with "I need to know the encryption" unless you **know** it involves encryption. Edit your question to start "I need to know the method used in the Automobile Industry to store meter values ...." - because the way you posted it is called a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an [instructables article on DIY Odometer Reprogramming](https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Odometer-Reprogramming/),

> Therefore the only characters that store actual information are the first two HEX digits, 33 and 85.

Here the only characters storing actual information are "05 49" and "15 6A" the rest of the characters are checksums.

```
String a = "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 05 49 B2 00 05".substring(33,38);
String b = "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 15 6A 81 00 15".substring(33,38);
a = a.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
b = b.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
System.out.printf("%s %s%n", a, b);
int i = Integer.valueOf(a, 16);
int j = Integer.valueOf(b, 16);

System.out.println(i/10.0);
System.out.println(j/10.0);
```

Which yields

```
0549 156A
135.3
548.2
```

And I can only assume 135.3 is ~136 and 548.2 is ~550. At least, if I was reading mileage I'd consider those pretty accurate descriptions.